# Using TypeLITE with Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, typelite

I'm using TypeLITE for creating some Typescript enums from my C# code. The output is something like this:

```
namespace Test.BL.Enums {
    export enum DayShift {
        PreviousDay = -1,
        CurrentDay = 0,
        NextDay = 1
    }
}
```

I came to the understanding this contructs are called 'internal modules' (if i'm right).

So I import the namespace in some other file like:

```
import Enums = Test.BL.Enums;
```

In design time this doesn't give any errors, but when i'm building my Typescript using the *awesome-typescript-loader* with Webpack the enums are not included.  And so I get an error on this when running the (Angular 2) application.

Is there a way to fix this problem? maybe disabling namespace generation in Typelite?

I also found this issue on github:

https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/246

Comment: Have you tried updating your tsconfig to use `preserveConstEnums`? And have you tried `ts-loader` to see if there's a difference in behavior?

Comment: @Jensdc do you got any solution for your Problem?